# my content div are misplaced when its contents are increased

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use three different class to differentiate my div. I write some contents inside these div. When the content inside first row div are same there is no problem but when the content are different it means when text inside those div different from one another second row div are misplaced. I also row class from bootstrap to separate those two row but the output is not like before when the text content and their size are same as first one.

my code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Bootstrap Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>

    body
    {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:400;
        color:#fff;
    }
    .main-body
    {
        margin-top:100px;
    }
    .back1, .back2, .back3{padding:15px; margin-bottom:30px;}
    .back1{background:#f1c40f;}
    .back2{background:#2ecc71;}
    .back3{background:#3498db;}

</style>

</head>



<body>

<div class="main-body">

    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back1">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back2">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back1">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back2">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>    

    </div><!--container closed-->    

</div><!--main-body closed-->    

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing another div with class `.row` on the last three columns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new row div for each rows. Currently you have placed all 6 child div in one row. Keep 3 in one row and another 3 in second. Below is update code. Hope this helps.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Bootstrap Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>

    body
    {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:400;
        color:#fff;
    }
    .main-body
    {
        margin-top:100px;
    }
    .back1, .back2, .back3{padding:15px; margin-bottom:30px;}
    .back1{background:#f1c40f;}
    .back2{background:#2ecc71;}
    .back3{background:#3498db;}

</style>

</head>



<body>

<div class="main-body">

    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back1">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back2">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back1">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back2">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="back3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>    

    </div><!--container closed-->    

</div><!--main-body closed-->    

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

To have all div of fixed height you can choose one of the two below solutions. It will help to handle dynamic text.
Solution 1

```
.back1, .back2, .back3 {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Solution 2

```
.back1, .back2, .back3 {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but  i don't need exactly  that you have done. Here first div and third div take more space bottom i  want to make all div take same margin bottom. Can you answer me how is it possible?

Comment: margin bottom is already applied by bootstraps css. You can do it by providing height to your div. Plz see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet..

OR

If you want to have all `div` to be fixed `height` than add `height` to `.back1`,`.back2`,`.back3`

```css
 body {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: #fff;
 }
 .main-body {
   margin-top: 100px;
 }
 .back1,
 .back2,
 .back3 {
   padding: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
 .back1 {
   background: #f1c40f;
 }
 .back2 {
   background: #2ecc71;
 }
 .back3 {
   background: #3498db;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Bootstrap Test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>



<body>

  <div class="main-body">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate
              eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
              quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back3">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
              quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back3">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
    <!--container closed-->

  </div>
  <!--main-body closed-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Snippet with `fixed` height..

```css
body {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: #fff;
 }
 .main-body {
   margin-top: 100px;
 }
 .back1,
 .back2,
 .back3 {
   padding: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   height:200px;
 }
 .back1 {
   background: #f1c40f;
 }
 .back2 {
   background: #2ecc71;
 }
 .back3 {
   background: #3498db;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Bootstrap Test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>



<body>

  <div class="main-body">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate
              eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
              quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back3">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
              quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="back3">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
              pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
    <!--container closed-->

  </div>
  <!--main-body closed-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible with out giving height to those divs?

Comment: i don't think without `height` it is possible